# Android sqlite database - where do i start as the tutorial has gone for notepad?

Tags: android, sqlite, datepicker, android-edittext

Ive tried to hunt down the tutorial for notepad on android developers but it appears to of gone offline with the recent change.

What i need is a database thats created by the user using 3-4 edittext boxes and 2 date boxes and to store as 1 file i can look back on..

but i have no idea where to start with databases..

ive read tutorials on how to make one but i cant work out what needs to change on the coding of the database for my needs,

i created one that generates a random word i set out of 5 words when i click an add button but that doesnt tell me what i need to do in order to get the information from my text input boxes and date pickers and display them in a listview..

Any help on this will be great.

ps. not looking for people to do it for me im looking to learn about databases.

Comment: Just in case you haven't noticed, [the tutorial is back](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)

Comment: a good sqlite android tutorial to start http://www.quicktips.in/basic-android-sqlite-database-exampletutorial/

Comment: you can get detailed and clear explanation regarding how to create a sqlite database here http://androidcoding.in/2016/03/22/android-sqlite-tutorial-on-inserting-deleting-values-into-database/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good point to start: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: +1, sneaking in there with the same link while I was typing

Comment: this is the one ive done.. i will read through this info as it was on a different site and only covered the sample on that page.. Thanks alot, very much appreciated

Comment: @Stefano "Use the latest version of Android 4.0. This is currently API Level 15. Otherwise I would have to introduce the Loader class, which should be used as of Android 3.0 for managing a database Cursor. And this class introduces additional complexity." Doesn't this mean it can't be used when targeting, for example, a minimum API level of 11?

Comment: I will not vote it down .. just the tutorial is not done properly. using android sample would be better.. or see :http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer with just a link, but that's pretty much what is required (I'm not going to post a whole tutorial as an answer  :p).

A good tutorial on databases is [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: thanks guys. Shame the tut for the notepads gone.. i have the sample and run it on my device but no idea what im looking at lol.. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Came across this in my own search.  Not sure if you're still interested but if anybody else comes across, it can help them out.  as of May, 2013, this is still active:  http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html