# Error when tring to implement SQlcipher in android

Tags: android, sqlcipher-android

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.sqlcipher_demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlcipher_android.so"

I am getting this error. i added all the jar files in libs folder n able to see .so files in all the folders. those jar files are also added in build.gradle file.

source : https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: Try this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34309425/1384010

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: Nope.. its not working @AdarshYadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for this....

If you maintain your project structure as mentioned below it will work

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8BOJ.png)

For further steps I followed

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/android-database-encryption-using-sqlcipher/

and now its working fine.