# How to use SQLCipher or any encryption and decryption techniques in Android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, security, sqlcipher-android

Guys i want to encrypt SQLite db which i am using in my android app. I know there are lots of thread on this topic but none gives detailed(step by step) info on how to do it. For a new person like me who is new to these things, i need brief steps on how to do it. Can anybody please help?? 
Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So finally i have found the way to encrypt my Android SQLite database. 
Please go through these two links:
[Integrating SQLCIPHER in Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048827/integrating-sqlcipher-in-android-studio-project/34309425#34309425)

and

http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-add-sqlcipher-to-your-android-app/

For a NewBee like me i found it very helpful.

Note:Links are useful Only to encrypt the new SQLite database(Android).