# Migrating issue of data base from SqliteDatabase to cipher Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlcipher-android

I am facing the issue `File is encrypted or is not a database` when trying to execute the query: `select count(*) from sqlite_master;` while migrating the database from `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` to `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase`.

I did not done anything in DBhelpher which is extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Can any one suggest what should I do to upgrade Android native db to sqlcipher db?

Comment: It may help [How to get started with SQLCipher for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671686/how-to-get-started-with-sqlcipher-for-android) and [SQLCipher for Android Application Integration](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android)

Comment: @Raghavendra:I am facing issue when am overriding the v1 app with v2 app.v1 have native sql integration v2 have cipher integration. Individually those are working fine.only facing issue at db migration means v1 already installed in device.done with v2 updating then am getting this issue.please suggest me

Comment: same issue for my app. did you find any solution?